# boto3: elastic beanstalk --> 'create_environment' with RDS DB instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3, amazon-rds

I have a web server, load balancing, auto scaling, vpc, beanstalk environment with RDS DB instance attached.

I use EB CLI [eb create](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html) with `--database` to create beanstalk environments.

I'd like to use boto3 [create_environment](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.create_environment) instead.

**Although I'm using [OptionsSettings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html) to define the RDS database configuration, it is creating the environment *without RDS*.**

**Does anyone know how to create an environment with and RDS instance using boto3?**

Here is the boto3 command I'm using with only the RDS portion of my OptionsSettings ():

```
eb_client = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk')

response = eb_client.create_environment(
    ApplicationName='APP',
    EnvironmentName='ENV',
    CNAMEPrefix='CNAME',
    Tier={
        'Name': 'WebServer',
        'Type': 'Standard'
    },
    SolutionStackName='64bit Amazon Linux ...',
    OptionSettings=[
        ...

        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBEngineVersion',
            'Value': '5.6'
        },
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBPassword',
            'Value': 'PASSWORD_HASH'
        },
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBAllocatedStorage',
            'Value': '5'
        },
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBInstanceClass',
            'Value': 'db.t2.micro'
        },
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBEngine',
            'Value': 'mysql'
        },
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBUser',
            'Value': 'ebroot'
        },
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBDeletionPolicy',
            'Value': 'Snapshot'
        },

        ...
    ]
)
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Because I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry no.  Aws support at the time confirmed that it wasnt possible with boto.  I'm not working with that system anymore so my information is out of date and there may have been a development i dont know about.